# nodeJS save post request of inputboxes in a file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, inputbox

```
var input = '';
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  input += <input name=line_"+i+ " type=text >"+"\n";
}
```

This cycle create HTML input boxes depending on the length of an array
and saves these in the string "input".
For each of them I assign the name `"line_"` and the number of index `i`,
for example the name of first will be `line_0`, the second `line_1` etc.

```
if (req.url == '/postContent') {
  var body = '';

  req.on('data', function(data) {
    body += data;
  });
  req.on('end', function() {
    var post = qs.parse(body);

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      fs.appendFile(databaseFile, "line" + i + ": " + post.line_ + "[" + i + "]" + "\n");
    }
    res.writeHead(302, {
      'Location': '/'
    });
    res.end();
  });
```

Now when there is a post request in one of the input boxes I want to save this in a file. I try to write **`post.line_+"["+i+"]`** but the program does not find the name of input boxes in fact the result is this:

`riga0: undefined[0]`

How can I do to write `post.line_i` "i" in the sense of variable.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

`post['line_' + i]`

Comment: I tried writing post. ['line_' + i] with the point and did not work.
Now I tried as you told me and it works, thanks a lot.